# What does this number represent in JetPack stats?

Tags: plugin-jetpack, statistics

[image]

When signed into my blog, this graphic is up on top. I know it shows visitor pattern over 48 hours, but does anyone know what the number represents? I searched on the WP site, and am not finding this.

Note to the closer - Jetpack is not 3rd party, it's owned by the WP people and part of the normal installation.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you sign in, You can see tiny site stats chart(displayed in above screenshot) in your toolbar called a Sparkline.

The number in Sparkline represents the highest number of visitors visited in 48 hours of day.

You can find more information in [wordpress.com Stats Support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/).

I have copy pasted the content below from this link so that  it will not affect  if that link ever changes its content in future.

> You can also access your Site Stats page via the tiny stats chart in
>   your toolbar called a Sparkline. The chart consists of 48 upright bars
>   representing the last 48 hours of page views for the current blog,
>   with darker lines indicating nighttime page views. Note that the
>   toolbar will only appear when you’re logged in to WordPress.com.

Comment: The number does not change while hovering. It looks to me like it's the highest hourly visit count over the 48 hour period, correct? (The link and quote are as far as I had gotten, and don't discuss the number appearing in that box)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer yes you are correct.. it is the highest hourly visit count over the 48 hour period..